# How to use xmlpullparser

Tags: xmlpullparser

```
public class MainActivity_Party extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    Button parse;
    TextView test;
    TextView test2;
    TextView test3;

    String Url = "http://abc13.dothome.co.kr/board.xml";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_party);

        parse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.parse);
        parse.setOnClickListener(this);
        test = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.main_test);
        test2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.main_test2);
        test3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.main_test3);


        try{
            test.setText("aa");
            URL url = new URL(Url);
            XmlPullParserFactory parserCreator = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser parser = parserCreator.newPullParser();
            parser.setInput(url.openStream(), null); 
            int parserEvent = parser.getEventType();
            String tag;


            while(parserEvent != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){

                switch(parserEvent){

                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                        tag = parser.getName();
                        test.setText(tag);

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:

                        tag = parser.getName();
                        test2.setText(tag);

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:

                        tag = parser.getName();
                        test3.setText(tag);
                }



            }



        }catch(XmlPullParserException e){
            Log.i("XMLLLLLLLLL","XmlError@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");   
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("EXCEPTIONNNNNN","EXCEPTIONNNNNNNNN");
        }
```

Hi, i'm begineer in android development.

I'm trying to parsing xml file in server, use xmlpullparser.

this is test code, but xmlpullparser not run.

testView's text was not changed..

What's wrong in this code?

Is this code can't read XML file, using URL and stream?

If not, what should I do?

please some help.

thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by not running?please post your logcat or explain your issue.

Comment: Please make your issue more clear ...

Comment: umm.. sorry for short english.

Comment: this code has not error, but can't read xml file in server..

Answer (score 0):

A little help here.
I see three issues not very good.

each case has to end with a break statement.

```
case x:
 x+=1;
 break;
case y:
   y+=1;
   break;
```

then you have to get the next event in the loop

```
parserEvent = parser.next();
```

The code be written faster if you didn't check for enddocument for every element in the file.

```
eventtype = xpp.getEvent();

while (true) {

//and if else if statements for the parser event the last statement being if end
//document {break}

eventtype = parser.next();
}
```